What's the difference between my OLS from scratch vs sklearn's OLS?
I'm coding linear regression via OLS from scratch. When I compare the results to scikit-learn's implementation, the coefficients in my version appear to be twice the magnitude of scikit-learn's.
I'm curious to know why?
Here's my OLS from scratch:
Y_mean = np.mean(Y_train)
X_mean = np.mean(X_train)

w = np.sum((X_train - X_mean) * (Y_train -Y_mean), axis = 0) / np.sum(np.square(X_train - X_mean) + eps, axis = 0)
b = np.sum(Y_mean - w * X_mean) / 2


weights [0.96521452 0.96521452]
Here's the scikit implementation, it's just a simple linear regression.
model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(X_train, Y_train)


Weights: [[0.48430039 0.48430039]]
The weights seem to differ, is my OLS wrong?
I notice the weights of my implementation from scratch are about twice the magnitude of sklearn's output.

have you tried checking the loss of the two of them?

yes the loss is perfectly fine, at a low value, for some reason.
just realized when i compute the weights via ols, I need to divide by number of features, which in my case was 2, thereby reducing the weights to the correct value.
